# Set the icon of a jLabel on mouseMove and change images over time

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, imageicon

I'm using netbeans and I had a jLabel the changes the icon when the mouse overlaps on a button(When you're about to click). My code:

```
private void BtnRoomsMouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
   jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/at/rosom.jpg")));
}
```

I want to make it change on time as long as the mouse still overlaps on the button. This makes it look like a screensaver.
What I have in my mind is I should use `Thread.sleep()`, but I don't have any idea of its proper use. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use a `MouseListener` just use the button rollover function

```
button.setIcon(icon);
button.setRolloverEnabled(true);

// create an instance of the RolloverIcon class when calling setRolloverIcon
button.setRolloverIcon(rollOverIcon);
```

No need for a timer or anything. Run simple example

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonRollover {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ImageIcon rollover = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://trustcloud.com/images/homepage-icon-source-stackoverflow.png"));
                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.pixelearth.net/images/icons/stackoverflow.png"));

                    JButton button = new JButton(icon);
                    button.setRolloverEnabled(true);
                    button.setRolloverIcon(rollover);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, button, "Rollover", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ButtonRollover.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

By the looks of this `BtnRoomsMouseMoved` it looks like you are using a `MouseMotionListener` when you should be using a `MouseListener`. When right click the button, instead of selectiing `MouseMotion`, select `Mouse` and you need to implement both the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited`. You can change your label icons back and forth in those methods.

Run this example

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonRollover {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final ImageIcon rollover = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://trustcloud.com/images/homepage-icon-source-stackoverflow.png"));
                    final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.pixelearth.net/images/icons/stackoverflow.png"));

                    final JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

                    JButton button = new JButton("Change Image");
                    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                            label.setIcon(rollover);
                        }
                        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                            label.setIcon(icon);
                        }
                    });

                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    panel.add(label);
                    panel.add(button);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Rollover", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ButtonRollover.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where to put that on netbeans?

Comment: In your constructor create the icons, then do the above.

Comment: Please explain it with more detail. I'm a very slow person. Sorry

Comment: First do you know what a constructor is? And do you know how to create an ImageIcon?

Comment: Don't know what a constructor is. Well, in netbeans, I just go to properties and setIcon

Comment: Nevermind. I'm not so used to netbeans, but there is also a `rolloverIcon` property. Same way you set the `icon`, you can set the `rolloverIcon`

Comment: There is. How can that change my jLabel's Icon? I want my jLabel's icon to change when my mouse overlaps a button.

Comment: What? So you don't want the icon on the button to change? But instead a different JLabel?

Comment: See my **EDIT** if you want to change the icon of a different label, and not the button.

Comment: About the **EDIT**, I want the label change like a screensaver while the mouse is on the button. More like a slideshow. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but if you don't even know what a constructor is, I'm going to suggest you put this project aside and first learn java basics. You have no business trying to create a GUI. You are learning backwards, which in no way is going to help you. Start from [**Java Baics**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) the go to [**Learning Swing**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) I really can't stand seeing people trying to learn Java from the GUI Builder. It's clear they have no idea what they're doing...

Comment: ..GUI Builder should only be a convenience tool for those who already know how to hand code.

Comment: Err.. I think when the mouse enters the button, the icon will change. Then when it exits the icon will change. That's not what I want sir. 
:( I want it to change like a slideshow when the mouse enters the button and stays there. If it exits, there will be no icon to show.

Comment: I think I know a constructor. Sometimes I just know something but I don't know what it is called. Yes, I'm trying to learn backwards so I can step forward twice. There's a reason why I'm doing this and 355 characters is not enough to explain it.